# Combine many joins into one join?

Tags: mysql, join

There are two tables - `incoming tours(id,name)` and `incoming_tours_cities(id_parrent, id_city)` where `id_parrent` is id from first table.

Here is the query i wrote

```
SELECT t.cities
FROM `incoming_tours` t
JOIN `incoming_tours_cities` tc0 ON tc0.id_parrent = t.id
AND tc0.id_city = '1'
JOIN `incoming_tours_cities` tc1 ON tc1.id_parrent = t.id
AND tc1.id_city = '6'
```

And now, what is the question...

Why i can't write both conditions in single join?(i.e. i can, but it returns empty result.)

as i understand joins, when i wrote

`JOIN incoming_tours_cities tc ON tc.id_parrent = t.id`

it must return the list of rows where the condition is true. isn't it?

So why i can't write

```
SELECT t.cities
FROM `incoming_tours` t
JOIN `incoming_tours_cities` tc ON tc.id_parrent = t.id
AND tc.id_city = '1'
AND tc.id_city = '6'
```

And maybe there is more efficient method to rich same effect(because in my structure the count of conditions can be very big)

Thanks much

Comment: I'm kinda wondering if you have a goofy database design... why is there a cities column on your incoming_tours table?  I'm thinking the names should in a city table.  It might be helpful if you explained what this query is trying to do.

Comment: ok, colomn `cities` has nothing to do with the query i demonstrated here. it's the list of `id_cities` from second table, and that's needed in another place of script. And what about the question "what this query is trying to do" : there is one main table - `incoming_tours` and a lot of other tables which store many tapes of data about each tour(incoming_tours_cities is one of such tables), And then i need to combine all data in one row. This part of script selects only that tours, which contain all required cities ...

Comment: Are you looking for multiple rows in your resultset, or just one?

Answer (score 0):

the value of tc.id_city cannot be both '1' and '6' simultaneously. I think you want an OR rather than an AND:

```
SELECT t.cities 
FROM `incoming_tours` t 
JOIN `incoming_tours_cities` tc ON tc.id_parrent = t.id 
AND (tc.id_city = '1' 
OR tc.id_city = '6')
```

Comment: the first query i wrote does exactly what i need. There is the list of `id_city` - s in second table for each `id` from first table, and i need to get rows where my **both** (or more) values are in that list

Comment: Right, but your second query is not the same as your first. The reason your second query is returning an empty set is because you're trying to retrieve a tuple that has multiple values for id_city when in fact each tuple has only one value for id_city. That was my point when I said that the value of tc.id_city cannot be both '1' and '6' simultaneously; rather it will be either '1' OR '6' for a given tuple. Hence, use an OR rather than an AND.

Comment: OR doesn't return what i need. Because when i use `OR`, it will return the row even if only one value matched, but i need both of them.
SO is there another way to achieve the result, which i got with first query?

Comment: What is the relationship between the two tables? Is it 1-to-1, 1-to-Many, or Many-to-Many?

Comment: the `id` of first table is `unique`, and it is the `id_parrent` of second table. so if in second tale i have rows - `('1','2')`,`('1','5')`,`('1','7')` it means that the element with `id = 1` in first table has the list of `id_city` - s `("2","5","7")`

Comment: ok, so you've established that 1 tour can have multiple cities; is it the case also that one city can belong to multiple tours? In other words, is it possible that the element with id = 2 in the first table can have the same list of cities as the element with id = 1?

Comment: yes, it's possible. the only relationship between tables is `id` -> `id_parrent` fields ...

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way.  If you ask for rows from incoming_tour_cities for which the id_city value is '1' *and is also at the same time* '6', how many rows will you match?

What you really want is:

```
 SELECT t.cities
 FROM `incoming_tours` t
 JOIN `incoming_tours_cities` tc ON tc.id_parrent = t.id
 WHERE (tc.id_city = '1'  OR  tc.id_city = '6')
```

or, more compactly:

```
 SELECT t.cities
 FROM `incoming_tours` t
 JOIN `incoming_tours_cities` tc ON tc.id_parrent = t.id
 WHERE tc.id_city IN ('1', '6')
```

Comment: I need exactly what the first query i wrote does(with many joins).

what you wrote, isn't same thing. it will return the row if even one value matched, but i need **both** of them.

Comment: If you want to perform both tests, you need to perform both tests.  That means two JOINs, or two EXISTs clauses.  There is one shorthand way of doing it, see my other answer.

Comment: OK,thanks much. And what will be faster, with `GROUP` -s, or with many `JOIN` -s?

Comment: You always have to test to determine what's fastest for your particular combination of row counts, column types, and indexes.  However, if you're really adding a lot of cities to the list I would imagine that the GROUP BY would be faster, and certainly it would be easier to write and to read.  If the conditions are more complex (some involve cities, some involve other factors) all bets are off and you'll have to test the various combinations.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer based on the user's clarification that the first query is the one he wants to duplicate.

Here is the only "short cut" way I know of doing this, where "short cut" means not performing two independent tests (using JOINs or EXISTs clauses):

```
 SELECT t.cities
  FROM `incoming_tours` t
  JOIN `incoming_tours_cities` tc ON tc.id_parrent = t.id
  WHERE tc.id_city IN ('1', '6')
  GROUP BY t.cities HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tc.id_city) > 2
```